# Partial inverse of a matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra

The partial inverse of a matrix, also known as principal pivot transform among other names, is defined as follows. if
$$
M\begin{pmatrix}x_a\\x_b\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}y_a\\y_b\end{pmatrix}
$$
then 
$$
\mathrm{inv}_a\, M\begin{pmatrix}y_a\\x_b\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x_a\\y_b\end{pmatrix}.
$$
That is, the partial inverse inverts the matrix over only some dimensions and not others. In general it is given by
$$
\mathrm{inv}_a\, M = \begin{pmatrix}
M_{aa}^{-1} & -M_{aa}^{-1}M_{ab} \\
M_{ba}M_{aa}^{-1} & M_{bb}-M_{ba}M_{aa}^{-1}M_{ab} \end{pmatrix}.
$$

My problem is that I would like to consider a partial inverse of a matrix of the form $e^H$, where I know the elements of $H$. (If it helps, $H$ is a real symmetric matrix in my case. It has column sums equal to zero and no off-diagonal negative elements.)

Is there a way to write down $\mathrm{inv}_a\, e^H$ in terms of a block decomposition of $H$? If not, is there anything useful that can be said about $\mathrm{inv}_a\, e^H$ in terms of properties of $H$?

Comment: the inverse of $e^H$ is $e^{-H}$. So your problem is the same as the calculation of $e^H$. There is no recipe for it, in terms of blocks of $H$.

Comment: @DenisSerre thanks, that's convincing. That just leaves the question of whether there's anything useful that can be said, short of an explicit recipe. (Which I admit is rather vague.)